Ingesting HLS into Mediapackage
I have the following setup for a streaming app.
EMX -> EML -> S3 -> LAMBDA -> EMP.
When I try to make a put request to mediapackage hls ingest endpoint, I get a 201.
def postStreamToMediaPackage(envVariables, fileName, content, contentType):
    mediaPackageUrl = envVariables["url"]
    username = envVariables["username"]
    password = envVariables["password"]
    ingestUrl = f"{mediaPackageUrl.rstrip('/channel')}/{fileName}" # not sure what mediapackage wants.

    response = requests.put(
        ingestUrl, data=content, headers={
            "ContentType": contentType
        }, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(username, password))
    if response.status_code != 201:
        print(
            f"Error ingesting file {fileName} to {ingestUrl}. error: {response.text}")
    return {"ingestUrl": ingestUrl, "fileName": fileName, "status": response.status_code}

But if i check mediapackage ingress access logs,

I can see for every file I send, it logs it twice, one that says 401 and the other one as a 201.

I've also noticed that the root manifest gets a 404 if I send it to `channel/{root manifest name}.m3u8 but any other endpoint gets the same behaviour as mentioned previously
To test this, I connected EML to EMP directly and enabled logging and can see that the request is send in the following style

channel_filename for all files

`channel_timestamp_sequence.ts for ts files

.m3u8 for root manifest


I've tried everything I can to get a positive response from mediapackage origin endpoint but it always returns a 404 for manifest.
Mediapackage hls ingest is a webDav server.
Has anyone tried doing this? I can't find any useful doc that says how they expect these.

After a lot of twiddling and tinkering, we discovered that mediapackage needs the following file name structure to get a successful push.
if fileName == "index.m3u8": # this is your root manifest
  ingestUrl = f"{mediaPackageUrl}.m3u8"
else:
   ingestUrl = mediaPackageUrl.replace('channel', fileName) # for all other resources, you need to feed it to the root endpoint.


Blog link https://www.craftsmensoftware.com/ingest-hls-stream-into-mediapackage/
